# How to capture DDL output messages such as "Table T successfully created" with Spring / JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jdbctemplate

I am using a Spring JDBC template to execute some DDL statements on Snowflake.  When I execute DDL in a worksheet in my browser, the statement shows an informational message such as "Table T successfully created.".  The Snowflake web interface (Snowsight) shows the result of the DDL statement as a single row result set with the message in a single column named "status".  I am trying to figure out how to capture this informational message in code as part of executing the DDL.

I am currently using the `jdbcTemplate.execute` method to run the DDL.  Browsing the Java docs for JdbcTemplate though, I can't figure out what to use to execute a DDL statement and capture the status message.